# What is the cause of BufferOverflowException?

Tags: java, nio

The exception stack is

```
java.nio.BufferOverflowException
     at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.put(DirectByteBuffer.java:327)
     at java.nio.ByteBuffer.put(ByteBuffer.java:813)
            mappedByteBuffer.put(bytes);
```

The code:

```
randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
fileChannel = randomAccessFile.getChannel();
mappedByteBuffer = fileChannel.map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, file.length());
```

and call `mappedByteBuffer.put(bytes);`

What is the cause  `mappedByteBuffer.put(bytes)` throws BufferOverflowException

How to find the cause ?

Comment: Can you show declaration of `bytes` ?

Comment: bytes is byte[] bytes

Comment: @fuyou001, what about the size of `bytes` ?

Comment: [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#put(byte[])) clearly says why...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[FileChannel#map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map%28java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long%29):

> The mapped byte buffer returned by this method will have a position of zero and a limit and capacity of size;

In other words, if `bytes.length > file.length()`, you should receive a `BufferOverflowException`.

To prove the point, I have tested this code:

```
File f = new File("test.txt");
try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rw")) {
  FileChannel ch = raf.getChannel();
  MappedByteBuffer buf = ch.map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, f.length());
  final byte[] src = new byte[10];
  System.out.println(src.length > f.length());
  buf.put(src);
}
```

*If and only if* `true` is printed, this exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.BufferOverflowException
at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.put(DirectByteBuffer.java:357)
at java.nio.ByteBuffer.put(ByteBuffer.java:832)
```

Comment: in fact ,the file.lenght is getter bytes.length.The file lenghts is 128M

Comment: the OS auto mapped file into memory ,why the buffer is not empty

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly because your byte array is bigger then the buffer.

[put(byte [] bytes)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#put%28byte%5B%5D%29)

I'd go by checking your file.length() and make sure that your memory buffer can actually be written.